# CSS styles priority

Tags: html, css

There is the following HTML:

```
<li class="tabs__item tabs__item_with_new_orders">123</li>
```

I want to do the following ones:

1. To set "tabs_item" CSS properties
2. Set background property from "tabs__item_with_new_orders" CSS class

Firebug shows me that this class is applied successfully:

```
.tabs__item:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #89c4bb;
}
```

My class is crossed in Firebug! And background property from "tabs__item_with_new_orders" are not applied. How can I fix it? I can use "!important" property to set priority, but I don't want to do it.

Comment: tried `!important`?..

Comment: Yes. But if I add some class using JQuery to this HTML item to change background again it won't work.

Comment: can you show your codes please?..

Comment: HTML or CSS? What do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
.tabs__item:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #89c4bb;
}

.tabs__item.tabs__item_with_new_orders {
    background: #000;
}
```

This way the background should be black because it gets overriden.

Comment: Uhm... okay? You sure everythings done right? I tried it and it worked in all common browsers.

Comment: Do you use any other styles which are overwriting the background property?

Comment: Sorry my friend, it works, I don't understand why it doesn't work at the first time. Please, edit your answer, because I can't upgrade my vote... Sorry again

Answer (score 0):

Avoid undescores in class and id. Why?:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Underscores_in_class_and_ID_Names